# Need jQuery solution to input size issue for edit onClick within Table Cell

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am **NOT** looking for a plug-in solution here! I would like the simplest way to solve this issue with minimal coding.

```
<code>
$('td.editable').live('click', function(){
     var newhtml = '<input value="'+$(this).text()+'" />';      
     $(this).html(newhtml);
     $(this).find('input').focus();
});
</code>
```

I have tried following with no success on accuracy of final width value when it comes to presentationally being same as original table cell.

```
<code>
$('td.editable').live('click', function(){
     var newhtml = '<input value="'+$(this).text()+'" />';
     var iwidth = (($(this).width()-15)>50) ? $(this).width()-15 : 50;      
     $(this).html(newhtml);
     $(this).find('input').focus().css('width', iwidth-22+'px');
});
</code>
```

Issue: As code indicates, I am trying to address the "width" issue for the input field. I would like the width of the input to be such that table cell does not have to re-size. I have tried specifying input size without units, and with "px, em...etc" units with no success.

Question: How can I make sure the input has correct width of the table cell it resides in. I can compensate and recalibrate differences caused by peddling, border and margin on my own.

My Expertise: 7 our of 10 in understanding of jQuery and its functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

```
$('td').click(function(){
    var input = $('<input/>').attr('value',$(this).text());
    var w = $(this).innerWidth();
    input.css('width',w).css('border','0');
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).append(input);
    input.focusout(function(){$(this).parent().text($(this).val());});
    input.focus();
});
```

I took the liberty of un-inputting on de-focus, as well.  Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cheeken/Wuunu/1/).

Comment: PS - I removed your `td` class only because I was lazy.

Comment: Lol, the changes worked great! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just to prevent possible issues, empty the input when you double click.

```
$('td').click(function(){
    if($(this).find('input').length==0) {
        var input = $('<input/>').attr('value',$(this).text());
        var w = $(this).innerWidth();
        input.css('width',w).css('border','0');
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).append(input);
        input.focusout(function(){$(this).parent().text($(this).val());});
        input.focus();
    }
});
```